How can I download R version 4.3.1 for MacOS?
I am trying to run an old R script in which I was using an older version of various packages, with the help of the groundhog package. My computer is running macOS 14.5 (23F79).
I was previously running my script with R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) but have since updated R.
I know how to install an older version of R from the archive and how to switch between R versions on macOS using RSwitch, but for some reason I cannot find this particular R version (4.3.1) anywhere in the archive at all! While I can find a different way to run my script, I am left with the question: Why is this older R version not in the archive even though I know for a fact I was previously using it? And is there a way for me to access R version 4.3.1?

You can officially download it from this link
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

More specifically https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/base/ or https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-x86_64/base/

Thank you @Roland, I found it there. I wonder why I was unable to find these files on the main site of the CRAN archive; it does not seem to be linked anywhere on https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ .
